# How can I convert this to use PDO?

Tags: sql, select, pdo

I  would like to use PDO for selecting (searching) a database.
The search 'form' has MULTIPLE fields that can be used.. 1 or many can be filled in to help refine the search.  (or there can be many o them left blank/empty)

here is what I have been using (locally):

```
//localhost details
$db_username="root"; //database user name
$db_password="";//database password
$db_database="test"; //database name
$db_host="localhost";

mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password);
@mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("Unable to connect to database.");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {  
    // define the list of fields
    $fields = array('first', 'trialdate', 'wcity', 'wstate', 'plantif');
    $conditions = array();

    //loop through the defined fields
    foreach($fields as $field){
        // if the field is set and not empty
        if(isset($_POST[$field]) && $_POST[$field] != '') {
            // create a new condition while escaping the value inputed by the user (SQL Injection)
            $conditions[] = "`$field` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field]) . "%'";
        }
    }   
    //build the query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM myTable ";
    // if there are conditions defined
    if(count($conditions) > 0) {
    // append the conditions
        $query .= "WHERE " . implode (' OR ', $conditions); // you can change to 'OR', but I suggest to apply the filters cumulative
    }   
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $row['first'] . "<br />"; //individual value
            //build panels that displays everything from row..etc
        }
    }
}
```

this has been working fine... but I'd like convert to using the PDO approach.

I gave it a few tries...but am missing something here..

heres what I've tried so far..

```
//localhost details
$db_username="root"; //database user name
$db_password="";//database password
$db_database="test"; //database name
$db_host="localhost";

//PDO DB connection
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.'dbname='.$db_database.'charset=utf8', $db_username, $db_password);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE first LIKE :first OR trialdate LIKE :trialdate OR wcity LIKE :wcity OR wstate LIKE :wstate OR plantif LIKE :plantif');

//build query placeholders (*note: use bindValue for $_POST values) 
    $stmt->bindValue(':first', '%' . $_POST['first'] . '%'); 
    $stmt->bindValue(':trialdate',  '%' . $_POST['trialdate'] . '%');
    $stmt->bindValue(':wcity',  '%' . $_POST['wcity'] . '%');
    $stmt->bindValue(':wstate',  '%' . $_POST['wstate'] . '%');
    $stmt->bindValue(':plantif',  '%' . $_POST['plantif'] . '%');

    $stmt->execute();

    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        // do something with $row
        echo $row['first'] . "<br />"; //individual value
    }
}
```

I could use help on getting the PDO example working with a displayed result/row/value?

Comment: anybody??  I'm very new to using PDO.. so I could use some direction. or pointers on what Im doing wrong here, as to not do the same in the future!

ps. what was edited yesterday? by @rink.attendant.6 ?  no message/comment.. just an EDIT?

Comment: You can click on the link "edited yesterday" to view the revision history of your post.

Comment: Thank you for informing me.  (Also is 'thanks' not allowed here? Seems thats what you edited out?)